# Carousel effect like amazon kindle android application

Tags: android, carousel, coverflow

I need to create coverflow like this

[image]

I have tried with [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) and [android-coverflow](https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/)

how can achieve look like kindle app

Comment: Consider this a viewpager with three items. You can find such custom viewpagers on github. Now , you can easily get the current viewpager item in center. If you can , you can increase that view's width and height to look bigger